# Magento 2.3 - How to hide empty attribute and it's label if there is no data

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product, product-attribute, product-detail-page

Could someone help me i want to hide the attribute if its have empty vale on product details page.

Example

```
<?php // START FABRIC ATTRIBUTE
    $attributeName = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('fabric_composition');
    if ($attributeName) {
    $labelValue = $attributeName->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
        }
    echo $labelValue;
    // END FABRIC ATTRIBUTE
      ?>
```

I have fabric_composition attribute i want to add if condition and want to hide if attribute value is empty
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You may use this Syntax:

```
<?php // START COLOUR ATTRIBUTE ?>
<?php $attributeName = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('fabric_description');?>
<?php if ($attributeName):?>
<?php $labelValue = $attributeName->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?>
<?php echo $labelValue;?>
<?php else:?>
<?php $labelValue ='';?>
<?php  echo $labelValue; ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Sorry getting syntax error

`<?php // START COLOUR ATTRIBUTE
 $attributeName = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('fabric_description');
 if ($attributeName) {
 $labelValue = $attributeName->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
  }
 echo $labelValue;
 else:
 l$abelValue ='';
echo $labelValue;
   ?>`

Comment: OH! you have just copied and pasted code at least look while copying code< See updated answer use that in phtml

Comment: NOTE: You can also remove else if you wish use only if condition

Comment: Thanks very much its working fine! One help more i also want to show attribute label with attribute value. I much appreciate your help

Comment: Good; please vote up to my answer as helpful thankyou and welcome  yes you can echo label with value easily

Comment: `<?php // START COLOUR ATTRIBUTE ?>
 <?php $attributeName = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('model_wears');?>
  <?php if ($attributeName):?>
 <?php $labelValue = $attributeName->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?> 
  <?php echo ("<strong>Model Wear:</strong> "); echo $labelValue;?>
 <?php else:?>
  <?php $labelValue ='';?>
  <?php echo (""); echo $labelValue; ?>
 <?php endif;?>
`
Could you please check i added this code but Model Wear: is still showing if the attribute value is empty i want to hide both if the attribute value is empty

Comment: You are doing wrong

Comment: use empty() function in if or echo attributename what is printing

Comment: Could you please help me how i can show and hide Attribute label and value like if its have value show label and value and if attribute don't have any value hide both label and value

Comment: Dear, I have Aswered above with code; you just need to apply that code where you want to do this, simply use if condition if you are wishing to hide both label as well as value or share your complete code

Comment: `<?php // START COLOUR ATTRIBUTE ?>
 <?php $attributeName = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('model_wears');?>
  <?php if ($attributeName):?>
 <?php $labelValue = $attributeName->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);?> 
 
  <?php echo __('<strong>Model Wear:</strong> '), $labelValue;?>
 <?php else:?>
  <?php $labelValue ="";?>
  <?php echo $labelValue; ?>
<?php endif;?>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130904/discussion-between-zahid-h-and-gilbertsohal).